# Форматирования числа, как отразить число 53500 в виде 53 500

Tags: android, kotlin

Весь интернет перерыл в поисках функции форматирования числа для вывода пользователю числа с разделением по разрядам, мне надо отражать число разбитое по разрядам, из "53500" получить "53 500" или "5200" "5 200".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120096/5479247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На java это делается так

```
Log.e("Пример", MessageFormat.format("{0} / {1} / {2}", 15552, 1555552, 155));
```

> 15 552 / 1 555 552 / 155

В Котлин переделать не проблема

Comment: Благодарю! То что надо

Comment: Поставьте тогда галочку, что проблема решена